# How to prove that a subset of a language L is related to NP while L is related to P?

Tags: complexity-theory, formal-languages, np

a friend sent me a question where we're given language $L$ and its subset $E(L)$ such that:

$$E(L)=\{E(w)\ |\ w\in L\}\\\text{such that}\\
E(w)=\{w_{even}=\sigma_2\sigma_4\dots\ |\ w=\sigma_1\sigma_2\dots\sigma_{n-1}\sigma_n\}$$

We need to prove that if $L\in P$ then $E(L)\in NP$.

***My Question:*** I'm finding it somehow hard or illogical to prove such a thing, that is if  $L\in P$ then $E(L)\in NP$ since $E(L)$ seems to be easier than $P$ and in the same time I couldn't find a polynomial algorithm that solves it. So if someone could give a hint on how to prove or any other help I'll be thankful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given a word $\sigma_2 \sigma_4 \sigma_6\dots$, nondeterministically guess $\sigma_1 \sigma_3 \sigma_5 \dots$ and check (in polynomial-time) whether $\sigma_1 \sigma_2\sigma_3\sigma_4\sigma_5\dots \in L$. If that's the case, accept. Otherwise reject.